# Theorem about convergence of power series solutions to DE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, power-series

I googled a bit and found this link with Fuch's Theorem: http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/series/series05/series05.html

I want something slightly more general:

Theorem (maybe): Consider the DE: 
$$
y^{(n)} + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} p_k(t) y^{(k)} = q(t)
$$
where $p_k(t)$ and $q(t)$ have power series representations centered at $a$ on an interval of radius $r$. Then the "power series solution" centered at $a$ to the DE converges (and is actually a solution) with radius $r$.

**QUESTION** Is this true? Is there a good reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewriting the equation as a first order system, you can use the theorem 4.2.1 of [Introduction to ordinary differential equations](http://www.math.unipd.it/~monti/ED2/PC5Maggio.pdf) by Roberto Monti:

> Let $\Omega\subset\Bbb R^{n+1}$ be an open set. If $f\in \Bbb C^\infty(\Omega;\Bbb R^n)$ is a real analytic function then any solution of the differential equation $y' = f(x,y)$ is also real analytic.

The idea of the proof is similar to that of [Cauchy–Kowalevski theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Kowalevski_theorem): the coefficients of $y$ can be recursively determined  in function of the coefficients of $f$.